# How Can I render a list dynamically using react-calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a list of classes scheduled in a certain date once the user clicks on this date, on the calendar, displayed on the App.

I am using [react-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar) for this.

I have made a test using `onClickDay` `function` available in order to see if it would render a list I had and it worked. So when I click on any day a list is rendered.

What I want now is to render a list related to the date picked on the calendar. E.g - Render all classes for Feb-13th upon clicking on the calendar on Feb-13th.

I imagine that I would need to set the date and time on the `array` of classes on my `state` so I could validate if the date picked on the calendar matches what was set on the `state` to render the appropriate list accordingly.

I did not find on the documentation of this library how to do this kind of validation that would compare the date in the calendar with whatever date I have on my `array` of classes.

please see the complete code [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-bouman-me4u6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Below is the print of this code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    classes: [
               { id: 1, name: "foo1" }, 
               { id: 2, name: "foo2" }
             ],
    displayClasses: false
  };

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date });
  displayClasses = () => {
    this.setState({ displayClasses: true });
  };
  render() {
    let classes = null;
    if (this.state.displayClasses) {
      classes = this.state.classes.map(cl => {
        return <li key={cl.id}>{cl.name}</li>;
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
          onClickDay={this.displayClasses}
        />
        <br />
        <ul>{classes}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The code is actually okay - Do you want to render specific components on a specific date? E.g. user clicks Feb-13th, and then something is being rendered for exactly that date?

Comment: yes sir! As this is my first time dealing with ```react-calendar``` I do not imagine how would i interact in between the calendar and my ```array``` of classes so I would render classes on specific dates, as per mentioned by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` handler gives you the date (as a date object), the user has clicked on as a first argument.

You could simply check if the date is your specific date where you would like conditionally display something. For example with `date.valueOf()`, you get the date in milliseconds.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    classes: [{ id: 1, name: "foo1" }, { id: 2, name: "foo2" }],
    displayClasses: false,
  };

  onChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
  };

  displayClasses = () => {
    this.setState({ displayClasses: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, date } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
          onClickDay={this.displayClasses}
        />
        <br />
        <ul>
          {date.valueOf() === 1581548400000 &&
            classes.map(cl => {
              return <li key={cl.id}>{cl.name}</li>;
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```